Sway: waybar doesn't start, GTK apps take more than 20 seconds to start up
I've been observing an unusual behavior from Sway on Fedora 39 (which also has GNOME installed, and I need to keep GNOME installed). The desktop starts up, but any GTK apps I launch won't open until about 25 seconds have passed. Also, my waybar never appears until I reload the configuration after the 25 seconds have elapsed.
How do I prevent this delay?
Answers I've seen and tried:

Uninstall xdg-desktop-portal and xdg-desktop-portal-gnome (it turns out these are dependencies for GNOME, so it isn't an option).
Set GTK_USE_PORTAL=0.
Set WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1.
Run exec systemctl --user import-environment in my sway config (I tried putting this before and putting it after the waybar line).
Comment out the pam_gnome_keyring.so line in a file under /etc/pam.d (in my case, /etc/pam.d/gdm-autologin).
Export a certain set of variables by name
(WAYLAND_DISPLAY, DISPLAY, XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP, etc.), so that systemd and dbus can use them.

Unfortunately, the delay persisted after a reboot with each of these changes. I'm posting this because I finally found a solution, but an explanation would be welcome (I don't really understand the solution).

Create a file ~/.config/xdg-desktop-portal/sway-portals.conf with the following contents:
[preferred]
default=wlr;gtk;

xdg-desktop-portal is indeed the problem. It requires a configuration file declaring which portals should be used and if it doesn't find one, it hangs for about 25 seconds before exiting. I found the right configuration here.
